# how to sort dictionary by value alphabeticallly?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So I have a dictionary, with keys and values, and the values are letters. I want to sort the dictionary so that it prints alphabetically according to the values, but I just can't figure out how to go about it.

For example, I have this dictionary:

```
dict = {5 : 'B', 7 : 'A', 9 : 'C'}
```

How do I get this to be sorted so that it prints out as follows?:

```
{7 : 'A', 5 : 'B', 9 : 'C'}
```

Comment: That output is impossible, you can only have each key once. `dict` (don't name dictionaries `dict`) only contains one key-value pair.

Comment: `dict` objects are inherently unordered - it doesn't make sense to say "a sorted dict"

Comment: Your dictionary itself is invalid.There can only be one key with the value `1` not three of them.

Comment: Sorry everyone. it was a typo. I made it so the keys are all different.

Comment: I'm a newbie, im sorry. Basically, i just want the values to be in alphabetical order, and have no idea on how to go about this.

Comment: A bad question maybe, but answering is as much effort as telling you about that. `sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) -> [(7, 'A'), (5, 'B'), (9, 'C')]`

Comment: @j.izzy again, *`dict` objects don't have an order*. It makes no sense to say "I want the dict to be in <whatever> order"

Comment: @Turksarama thank you! That's along the lines of what I was asking. Sorry i understand why my question is formatted incorrectly now D:

Comment: @turksarama when i use this method, it sorts the keys, and not the values. how do i get it to sort the values?

Comment: @Turksarama never mind! That method fixed my problem. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Dicts are unsorted, if you need something in a certain order for sure, use a list. Also, you can't duplicate keys.

to make a list:

```
your_list=['B','A','C']
#yay, now sort
your_list.sort()
```

Comment: Okay. How would I go about changing this to a list, and then sorting by the values, aka the letters?

Comment: There are other ordered data structures in Python besides lists (for example, a closer fit to a dictionary but with order might be an... [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?)

Comment: @j.izzy I updated to show the list part